# navigating a .Docset file in iphone app

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, doxygen, docset

I want to use a Docset i have created using Doxygen in my iPad app in a tableview, and navigate through the directories. then display the file i click.

How would i go about navigating the Docset? i can unzip it, then navigate the directories in that manner, though i'm certain there must be a way of using the file as is and then being able to run search queries on the database, etc.

Could someone please give me a pointer in the direction i should be looking?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

If you look inside of a docset bundle, there is a compiled .mom file (CoreData) and a couple of plist files (with various extensions). I do not think there is a straightforward way to consume all that data without knowing the schemas.

You should probably create your own core data schema, and index the HTML contents of the docset manually at the first run of your app, and reuse that for searching and such.

Comment: A Doxygen-created .docset contains the raw HTML files, at `DoxygenDocs.docset/html/*.html`. Those could be displayed in a `UIWebView`.

Comment: Hi Graham! :) sure, that's actually very easy to do, but I think the question has to do with the indexes and those files that appear in the docset. Just a comment tho, docsets generated by the latest version of Doxygen are Mac OS X bundles, with the HTML files in the Content/Resources folder, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Hello :). So what I see from one of my projects is a bundle DoxygenDocs.docset laid out as I described. Inside _that_ is com.fuzzyaliens.MyProduct.docset, which has the HTML in Contents/Resources/Documents and also has the binary indices. The compiled .mom is a binary plist as you say so that part is quite easy to parse, it should be possible to write a tool to read in the index files.